# Performing calculations on dynamically generated rows (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to perform some calculations on some dynamically generated rows in my table.The dropdowm options all carry numerical values and based on the values the RiskOfObsctacle and ValueOfObstacle will be calculated:
ValueOfObstacle= Likelihood*Severity*Principal;
RiskOfObsctacle= Likelihood*Severity;

I dont have any problem adding/deleting rows but the problem is displaying the results after values are entered.

Here is my jquery code for generating the rows:

```
function addRow(tableID) { 

var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.type = "checkbox";
element1.name="chkbox[]";
cell1.appendChild(element1);

var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell2.innerHTML="<textarea name='Obstacle[]' cols='20'>";

var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
cell3.innerHTML = "<select name='Likelihood[]'> onKeyup='calc() <option value='1'>Low</option> <option value='2'>Medium</option><option value='3'>High</option>/>";

var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
cell4.innerHTML = "<select name='Severity[]'> onKeyup='calc() <option value='1'>Low</option> <option value='2'>Medium</option><option value='3'>High</option>/>";

var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
cell5.innerHTML = "<select name='Priority[]'> onKeyup='calc() <option value='1'>Low</option> <option value='2'>Medium</option><option value='3'>High</option>/>";

var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
cell6.innerHTML = "<input type = 'text' name='Principal[]' required placeholder='100.3' onKeyup='calc()'>";

var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
cell7.innerHTML = "<input type = 'text' name='ObsRisk[]'  readonly value onKeyup='calc()'>";


var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
cell8.innerHTML = "<input type = 'text' name='ObsValue[]' readonly onKeyup='calc()'>";

}
```

And here is the code for performing calculations:

```
function calc (){
$('.Likelihood, .Severity, .Principal').change(function(){
var value = 0;
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
var like = parseFloat($row.find('Likelihood').val());
var sev = parseFloat($row.find('Severity').val());
var prin = parseFloat($row.find('Principal').val());
value = like*sev*prin;
if (isNaN(value)) {
$row.find('.ObsValue').value("Nix is");
}
else{
$row.find('.ObsValue').val(value);
}
calc();
});
}
```

Also based on the results the color of the text should change i.e. green if positive and red if negative. Thanks for the help.

[image: Obstacle Table]

Please, let me know if more info is needed!

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you using plain JavaScript to create the rows? Also, your selects have no classes, but the jQuery you posted targets several, `$('.Likelihood, .Severity, .Principal')`. So your code example seems to be incomplete.

Comment: It is always  a good idea to create a jsfiddle for questions like this.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will change the code using jQuery in a few minutes.. and post a link for the jsfiddle too. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple things going on in here.

1. Your markup should be cleaned up a bit to add classes to the items to reference them in the rows. Having "class='Likelihood'" will allow you to reference the elements.
2. Your calc function should be a handler for a change event binding. Also, in the calc event, you have a couple jQuery syntax errors like your "find('Severity')" and ".value()" calls.
3. I can't see it here in your sample, but make sure you are binding all of this in the "ready" event for jQuery. Otherwise, if this is in the head of the page, you are trying to bind to the elements before they exist. And...
4. You should use jQuery ".on" to bind the change event handler to the table so it works for dynamically added elements like the following:

```
$(function() {    // jQuery ready shorthand
    $('#myTable').on('change','.Likelihood,.Severity,.Principal', function(e) { 
        /* something */ 
    }
});
```

All that said, I put together two fiddles for you to clean it up and show it working. The first one is just a copy of what you put with a few things cleaned up to make it work. I added the classes, cleaned up some of the syntax errors, and then bound the events in the ready handler. The "onkeyip" is still there, but not being used. I also left "calc" as it's own function if you wanted to use it from other elements, but the contents really could be an anon function as the handler for the change event.

The second fiddle is a little different. What you are doing, just from what I can see, lends itself really well to templating and data-binding. I used the JSViews package, with JSRender, and JSObservable and included your markup as a template in the page. It takes a little getting used to, but it's nice for UI work and makes managing markup like you are rendering much easier since it's actually HTML with data-binding (data-linking for JSViews). You can read up on it here: http://www.jsviews.com/#home

Basically, you can create objects and arrays and bind them and their properties to elements in a page or template for dynamic rendering. If you have heard of Model View View Model (MVVM) it's what helps make it work. With two-way binding, any changes to the UI in terms of inputs or similar, changes the object or array (model). Any changes to the model via script is displayed in the template (view). It can get pretty complex, but your situation lends itself to a fairly good one for starting. It makes it nice to add to, remove from, and modify objects or an array of objects. In the example I provided, the add and remove just update the model with a new empty object, for example, but the UI updates with a new table row. And the template for the row is stored in a script tag in the HTML so it's really easy to work with.

Anyways, after all that and my .02 cents, below are the links. Ask questions and pick what's easiest for you. However, if you do much work with dynamic rendering of large blocks of HTML, look into templating.

Fiddle for original: http://jsfiddle.net/Hps25/

Fiddle for templating: http://jsfiddle.net/sW33n/2/

**Update:** If you use the templating method, the data for the obstacles is already constructed into a single array of objects based on the rows created. That's the great thing about the templating approach: you add a row, it adds an item to the array. Then, when you want to use it, you just use the array, in this case *obstacles*. This, then, makes it super easy to use for posting to a service to update items in a DB, for instance. Using AJAX you can pass an object as **"data"** that will get serialized into a string. Deserialize it at the server into an object and you can do what you wish.

I updated the fiddle to show an example of this, passing the obstacles array along with a single value from a "made-up" select element. Obviously the serverside piece would still need to be defined.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sW33n/4/

Comment: Thanks @David for that solution. Thank is exactly what i was looking for!! Another question though.. I have a similar page with checkboxes and table too (i.e GoalName, GoalDescription, GoalDate, etc). After checking the boxes and submit button, i would like to open a new page with just the GoalName of the checked rows and run sql to display all my registered users in my db on a table next to the GoalNames so in the new table there'll be (RegisteredUser, GoalName, Checkboxes) and an invite button at the end of it. is there a way to do this.. perhaps a pseudo?? thanks so much

Comment: I haven't done PHP in years so I am not going to be much help on specifics. If you have the data on one page and want to pop open another and display records based on that data, though, an easy approach might be to do a form submit. I'm assuming you want to get all the users registered for each goal and display them all in a cell next to the GoalName field. It sounds like you want to do a mass invite to everyone registered for a goal? Anyways, in PHP I believe it's $_POST['key'] to get the values posted to a page. You would probably want to loop through that and query based on the values.

Comment: Actually i figured out that was a rather less intuitive way of dealing with the problem. Instead of that, i would like to run an sql query on all the goalsNames in the my database and display in form a dropdown menu. once the goal is clicked then the table you've helped with above will be displayed. So for each/selected goal, a user can enter as much obstacle as possible.. if you could help or i could post as new question? thx

Comment: Might be best as a new question. I'll check it out too though. ;)

Comment: @David, how can i use ajax to store the rows into a database?

Comment: You will need a server side component to handle the DB access. In the .Net world, I would use a Handler, REST service, or Web service and I would post the data to whatever I chose as a JSON string. Then, in my server side code, I would deserialize the JSON string into an object and use that to populate my DB rows. The second fiddle has the save click already bound with the JSON stringify used already. Post that string with AJAX and you have your data. For PHP json handling see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php

Comment: ok thanks. so i could simply do something like this: $('.save').click(function (e) {
 $('#savedDiv').html(JSON.stringify(obstacles));
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {'Obstacles', opt : options}//I have another dropdown menu i would like to submit aswell
  url: 'saveObstacles.php',
  success: function(data){
   alert(data + 'success');
  }});});

Comment: You're close. I updated the fiddle to show how to utilize the data in the template. If you don't use the templating method, you need to get all the values into a json string before sending via ajax.

Comment: I'm sticking with the templating method! would i need to encode then decode on the server-side then? also would i need to use the $_POST[''] to get the values since i'm using a table and not a form? so sorry for all the questions. really appreciate it. thanks

Comment: When you perform an ajax post like you see in my Fiddle example, it actually sends them as parameters. Where the name would be the key in the query for the Post when using a form, the key in the JSON object will be the key in the query with ajax. This screenshot shows the parameters and the query created http://screencast.com/t/j6wzV4A87xg. You access the params just like a form post. You need to decode JSON string serverside and encode if sending a response.

Comment: i tried what you suggested i.e. on my .php file, i used $_POST['Obstacles'] to try get the value in that field. However, i could get the value of my dropdown option and save it ok to my db. This is what i tried in my .php: $data=json_decode(stripslashes(file_get_contents('php://input')));
$newData = $data->{'Obstacle[]'};
echo $newData; i'm quite sure i.m decoding right.. also i think i'll need to loop through the body of the table to get each content?? thanks

Comment: We're getting into more of a discussion than they like to see in comments, but I'll provide what I can. Unfortunately, I don't work with PHP directly anymore so I can't offer advice on that, and would suggest maybe posting a question about working with JSON in PHP. That said, if you're looking at my last fiddle with templating, you'll see "obdata" in the ajax post. It's a JSON string of all the table values. Once you decode, you have them all in an object. Templating updates the obj array when values update. No need to loop through table body.

Comment: please see my new question on how to generate a matrix table using js/jquery. your help is much appreciated. thanks : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099841/creating-a-multidimensional-array-nxn-matrix-using-javascript